# tcolorbox middle key misunderstood

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to make a tcolorbox with no space between the 2 part but I don't manage by using `middle` key. I would like the A and the B to be glue the red line.
It seems that middle do not have any effect.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,  title=test 1,
  colframe=black!50, sidebyside=true,
  boxsep=0pt, right=0mm, left=0pt, toptitle=1mm, bottomtitle=1mm,
  top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=0mm, lefttitle=4mm, middle=0mm,
  segmentation style={solid, red},]

  \hfill A
  \tcblower
  B
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,  title=test 1,
  colframe=black!50, sidebyside=true,
  boxsep=0pt, right=0mm, left=0pt, toptitle=1mm, bottomtitle=1mm,
  top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=0mm, lefttitle=4mm, middle=10mm,
  segmentation style={solid, red},]

  \hfill A
  \tcblower
  B
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,  title=test 1,
  colframe=black!50, sidebyside=true,
  boxsep=0pt, right=0mm, left=0pt, toptitle=1mm, bottomtitle=1mm,
  top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=0mm, lefttitle=4mm, middle=40mm,
  segmentation style={solid, red},]

  \hfill A
  \tcblower
  B
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `sidebyside gap=0mm`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer perfect !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `sidebyside gap=0mm`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,  title=test 1,
  colframe=black!50, sidebyside=true,
  boxsep=0pt, right=0mm, left=0pt, toptitle=1mm, bottomtitle=1mm,
  top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=0mm, lefttitle=4mm,sidebyside gap=0mm,
  segmentation style={solid, red},]

  \hfill A
  \tcblower
  B
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]